# Error when building Ionic APP using Cordova

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework

(node:16112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171

I checked my user environment variable and I have the variable JAVA_HOME and set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171"

I also have C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171 appended to the user environment variable PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> make sure you have a JDK installed

This is the relevant part of this error message. Your `JAVA_HOME` points to a Java Runtime Environment (JRE), not to a Java Development Kit (JDK).

`javac` is the Java compilation command, which Cordova is attempting to execute in this case. However, `javac` is not shipped with the JRE as it is a development tool.

You need to download and install a [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and set `JAVA_HOME` to point to it

Comment: Wow..... that was it... something so simple yet I overlooked it 100 times. I downloaded the JDK, set the variables and now it successfully built. Thank you very much